# changing a tkinter button color by pressing another button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the background color of Button2 by pressing Button1. Here is what I do:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.Frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.Frame.pack()

        self.Button1 = Button(self.Frame, text = "Button 1", command = self.button1_press)
        self.Button1.pack()

        self.Button2 = Button(self.Frame, text = "Button 2")
        self.Button2.pack()

    def button1_press(self):
        self.Button2.config(bg = "red")

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But pressing Button 1 does nothing. Any help?

Comment: It works in my Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Works with Python3.5  as well

Comment: Works with Python3.7 on Windows 7 as well.